# How to avoid table break issue in XSL FO?

Tags: xsl-fo

I am using XSLFO for generating PDF file.

My PDF page contain some text, then it contain one table, if the table row size is increasing then entire table is not coming within a page.   some rows are coming in the next page.
I want some thing that if the table can fit within the page then it should be start from a new page instead of breaking the table some row in one page and some row in another page other wise as usual.

Answer (score 2):

If the table will fit within one page, you could use `keep-together="always"` on the `fo:table`.  If the table might or might not be longer than one page, you could use `keep-together` with a numeric value -- for example, `keep-together="1"` -- but how well that works will depend on which XSL formatter you are using.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#keep-together and https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#keepbreak.

Alternatively, you could use `keep-with-next` on every `fo:table-row` (except the last) or `keep-with-previous` on every `fo:table-row` (except the first), but unless the `fo:table-row` also has a `keep-together` value, that might not stop the table row from breaking. Again, how well a numeric value works will depend on which XSL formatter you are using.